# Load UIViewController on another UIViewController in UIStoryboard from xib

Tags: iphone, xib, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have a UIViewController(Say A). A separate nib file was loaded as popup on this view controller. When popup was closed by clicking a UIButton, I want to load  another view controller(Say B) in UIStoryBoard. All the UIViewControllers were in storyboard.

I tried with delegates pattern. the delegate method returns self.storyboard as **nil**.

Please suggest how to handle (either performsegue from A to B or pushing new instance of B on navigation controller from nib file)

Here is code I used for delegate:

```
**In CustomViewNewPrescription.h file:**

    @class CustomViewNewPrescription;
    @protocol CustomViewNewPrescriptionDelegate <NSObject>
    -(void)SaveCustomViewNewPrescription;
    @end 
    @interface CustomViewNewPrescription : UIView{
        id<CustomViewNewPrescriptionDelegate>delegate;

    }

    @property(nonatomic,strong) id<CustomViewNewPrescriptionDelegate>delegate;

    **in .m:**
    - (IBAction)btnCancel:(UIButton *)sender{
        [self.delegate SaveCustomViewNewPrescription];
    }

delegate was synthesized and initialised.

**In AddNewRx.h:**
@interface AddNewRx : UIViewController<CustomViewNewPrescriptionDelegate>{
}

**in AddNewRx.m:**

-(void)SaveCustomViewNewPrescription{
   //either self performseguewithidentifier .... (or)
    RxViewController *obj1 = [[self.navigationController storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RxViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj1 animated:YES];
}
```

In SaveCustomViewNewPrescription, self.storyboard giving nil values

Please suggest how to load another view controller in SaveCustomViewNewPrescription.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
RxViewController *obj1 = [[self.navigationController storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RxViewController"];
```

Try:

```
UIStoryboard *yourStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
RxViewController *obj1 = [yourStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RxViewController"];
```